# Impersonating user account fails in SQL 2016 SMO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-smo

I am running a Windows WCF service using local system account and from within the service we are trying to connect to SQL Server instance using SMO with domain user account.

The code shown below works fine is I am using SMO from SQL Server 2014 SDK, but if I use SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.2 SMO then it throws an exception saying that

> Login Failed for user {domain}{local machine name}

wherein I have given domain admin credentials in server connection object.

```
var srvConnectionConn = new ServerConnection("WIN-DVGQDI73QR6");

srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUser = true;
srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUserName = @"administrator@mva";
srvConnectionConn.ConnectAsUserPassword = "*****";

srvConnectionConn.ConnectTimeout = 60;
srvConnectionConn.NonPooledConnection = true;

Server srv = new Server(srvConnectionConn);
srv.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(LogFile), "Name", "FileName");
srv.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(FileGroup), "Name");
srv.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(DataFile), "Name", "FileName");

Database db = srv.Databases["DB_H"];
bool bRemote = db.RemoteDataArchieveEnabled;
```

**Note: if I run my windows service through domain admin account instead if local system account then the below code works fine w/o having any exception.**

It looks like SQL 2016 SMO binaries are not able to impersonate the given user account.

Regards

Ashish

Comment: The error means that instead of impersonating a Windows account, the current machine account was used. Is the user's account name `MVA\Administrator`? Have you tried to use this form?

Comment: Yes the user account name is  MVA\Administrator.  I have tried by connecting with this account as well but I am getting an exceptions saying that "User name or password is incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned code started working as expected in SQL 2016 RC3 release.
I guess there was a bug in SQL 2016 CTP3.2 which was causing this error in impersonating the user account.

~Ashish